# Pandas: date calculation and check is date exceeds date today

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a dataframe with a date column. I need to add 6 months to the date column and check if that date exceeds the date today. I only want to see the rows that exceed the date today. The column is a datetime type.

**dataframe:**

```
         date

row1     2022-04-08 10:17:00
row2     2022-09-11 11:37:00                        
row3     2022-07-10 10:34:00                             
row4     2022-07-10 10:44:00                            
row5     2022-08-11 10:11:00
```

**I tried:**

I can add 181 days to the date column via pd.timedelta but I don't know show or filter based on the date today.

**expected result:**

Example with todays date 2022-12-06

```
         date                  date+6m

row1     2022-07-10 10:34:00   2023-01-07 10:34:00  
row2     2022-08-10 10:44:00   2023-02-07 10:44:00
```

Another option would be to show a column with a true and false but I prefer to see the actual date. Maybe that can be an extra column.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To add six months to your date, use `offset`: `df["date_plus_6m"] = df["date"] + pd.DateOffset(months=6)`

If you want to filter the rows based on today's date, you can use `datetime.date.today()`: `df = df[df["date_plus_6m"] > current_date]`!

Comment: But please post a minimal reproducible code / problem so we  can help out properly.

Comment: My apologies, will take note for further questions. Question: I have manually add the date  instead of "current_date" because that generates an error. Is there a way to auto-detect the todays date and place that in the code? Thx!

Comment: Use `datetime.date.today()` for that.